# UPDATE command not updating data

Tags: c#, sql

I have two oledbcommnds used for updating a table in a database.One of them is working (adding data to empty fields) but the other one designed to empty the data, does not work.Any ideas?

First Update commnd that is working (adds values to empty data):

```
conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter3.UpdateCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
adapter3.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET Occup=Yes, Profesor=?";
adapter3.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", "name");
adapter3.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

The second one, that does not work (replaces values)

```
conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter3 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter3.UpdateCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
adapter3.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET Occup=No, Profesor=?";
adapter3.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", "replace_prof_name");
adapter3.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

When running the second code, I don't get any errors. I have put a counter and it shows the correct number of operations but I see no modfifications.

Comment: Occup=No in the second example seems to cause issues - "No" can be a reserved sql word so if it is executed without any escaping (like Occup='No') then query may behave strange

Comment: you are referring `adapter3` instead of `adapter1`

Comment: @tchrikch It **is** a reserved keyword but this should give an error as: `"Incorrect syntax near by..."`. OP says he didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are **wrongly** referring `adapter3` instead of `adapter1`..

Try this

```
conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter1.UpdateCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
adapter1.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET Occup=Yes, Profesor=?";
adapter1.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", "name");
adapter1.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter3 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter3.UpdateCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
adapter3.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET Occup=No, Profesor=?";
adapter3.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", "replace_prof_name");
adapter3.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: They are not in the same function so it does not matter what name I use.

Comment: @yes but declaration and definition name should be same. See you first part